# How to keep original name after running command line tool?

Tags: cmd.exe, imagemagick

I am running imagemagick (CLI tool) to splice an image into 16 equal parts.

I am using it like so :

```
convert inputfile.jpg -crop 4x4@ +repage +adjoin -resize 256x256 output_4x4_%03d.jpg
```

I'd like to keep the name of the original file, inputfile.jpg, and use that as the output instead of "output_4x4..." automatically i.e without having to change it every time, so I can run this automatically on a bunch of files, and keep their original names.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick 6 and 7, you need to get the name first.

```
name=$(convert inputfile.jpg -format "%t" info:) 
convert inputfile.jpg -crop 4x4@ +repage +adjoin -resize 256x256 ${name}_4x4_%03d.jpg
```

One might think you could use the -set filename option as for example:

```
convert inputfile.jpg -set filename:fn "%t" -crop 4x4@ +repage +adjoin -resize 256x256 "%[filename:fn]_4x4_%03d.jpg"
```

But this will not resolve the %03d. It will give results such as

```
inputfile_4x4_%03d.0.jpg
inputfile_4x4_%03d.1.jpg
inputfile_4x4_%03d.2.jpg
inputfile_4x4_%03d.3.jpg
```

If you remove the _%03d, you will simply get

```
inputfile_4x4.jpg
```

At least that is what happens on my Mac.

Comment: If you set the filename with "-set filename:fn '%t'" after the crop, and write the final output files like "%[filename:fn]%02d.png", it -almost- works. An apparent bug truncates the original input name. However, if you put the number first like "%03d%[filename:fn].png", the multiple output files are named as expected.

Comment: Greg, that is interesting. It does indeed work if you put the %03d at the beginning. I tried `"%03d_%[filename:fn].png"` and that does work. But odd that it won't work at the end even if one does `_%[filename:fn]_%03d.png`, which produces names like `_lena_%03000.png`